# Finding a function which maps two variables $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $y$ with given points

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

I'm trying to determine a function/equation that would "solve" the following mapping (apologies for the super wide table):

| $x_1$ | $x_2$ | $y$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 0 |
| 3 | 4 | 1 |
| 3 | 5 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 4 | 4 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 |
| 5 | 4 | 7 |
| 5 | 5 | 8 |
| ... | ... | ... |

I've been trying to solve this for a while now, but I'm not sure how to approach it other than by randomly trying different combinations of transforms. Is it even solvable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x_1=3, y=x_2-3$.  When $x_1=4, y=x_2.$  When $x_1=5, y=x_2+3$.

So  $y=x_2+3(x_1-4)=3x_1+x_2-12$.

(I can say at least that choice matches all the data given.)

Comment: I extrapolated this to more values that continue matching the sequence and it works! Thanks